# How do I plot ternary phase diagrams using Flory-Huggins solution theory?

Tags: thermodynamics, solutions, phase

I have three components, $A,B,C$, with 3 exchange parameters: $\chi _{AB}, \chi _{BC}, \chi _{AC}$. I want to create a FH ternary diagram to see how such a mixture behaves and how phase separation takes place i.e find points on the ternary plot where I will see $(A+B,C), (A+C,B), (B+C,A), (A+B+C), (A,B,C)$, where $I+J$ represents a mixed phase of $I,J$ and a separation by a comma $","$ indicates the third species is in a different phase.

The ternary spinodal condition is:
$$D=\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial \phi _B ^2}\Bigg|_{N,T,\phi_A}\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial \phi _A ^2}\Bigg|_{N,T,\phi _B} - \left( \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial \phi _B \partial \phi _A} \Bigg| _{N,T}\right)^2 = 0$$

My question is, how do I find the regions on the ternary plot indicated above? How do I find the region where two species are mixed while the third one is not?

I am not quite sure what it means when A+B is in a mixed state and when C is not. Does this mean that $\mu _A = \mu _B \neq \mu _C$?

This is basically the figure I want to make [from this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ma00128a005):
[image]

I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: Do you have discrete data points?  If so, did you query the net for plotters of *ternary data*?  Online like https://www.ternaryplot.com/, https://ternaryplot.netlify.app/, on-site for Windows like [past4](https://www.nhm.uio.no/english/research/resources/past/), or OS independent with [Python/plotly](https://plotly.com/python/ternary-plots/)?  Wolfram seems to be there, too [example](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TernaryDiagram.html).

Comment: @Buttonwood, thanks for your reply. my question is more along the lines of how does one obtain these points from the FH free energy.

Comment: If it were me, I would run the calculations using fixed C concentrations and vary across A-B concentrations, searching for common tangents to get phase boundaries in the pseudo binary system. Vary C in small steps to get whatever density of points you need…